# For User i am giving option of color selections for a theme

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I am giving user the option of selecting the color(color scheme option like bartik) for the theme.For multiple users how do i save there color values for the theme and show their values alone depending on their login ? Colors for their header ,footer etc...

Help me provide with a solution.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

well, usually there are pre-defined color sets (like in batrik), so you save set name and then on hook_preprocess_page you chose which css to include.
So either this or you can add inline css styling using the same function [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7).

As for how to save this for each user, you can add extra field to user profile at Home » Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings
and then programmatically update it with needed value - example below, details [here](https://drupal.org/node/1047600).

```
global $user;
$existing = user_load($uid);
unset($existing->pass);
$edit = (array) $existing;
$edit['field_somefield']['und'][0]['value'] = 'blah';
user_save($user, $edit);
```

Comment: In a single site i am trying to give each user there own option of changing colors(example: changing header color,footer color etc like bartik theme).

For that to happen what i did is actually tried creating each user a their own css files in (sites/default/files/color/1-firehouse/colors.css) and generate it.

Depending upon the user logged in i am including the generated css file alone. So it works properly.

Comment: But only issue over here is that, when i try once again to change the theme colors(header,footer etc) after logged in, if some other user has changed previously their colors, that is applied in view section alone(color scheme options) instead of current logged in user color scheme options. Just viewing of colors alone.Colors are applying properly.Only color scheme default value option is not user selected one.

Comment: I tried debugging it in color module. This is the function color_get_info i think which is responsible in rendering the color information for a particular theme, but i dont know how to make it load user selected css,but way too complex. I have digged much deeper into this, so i expect some results from this. Any help will be really appreciated :)

Comment: Hope you understood the way i am trying to do it?

Comment: How do you change colors for logged in users?

Comment: For each user i am creating a seperate css files and storing them over here like sites/default/files/user-id(1)/colors.css. So in html.tpl.php depending upon user logged in using uid i am including those css file alone.

Comment: That is not issue. Only issue is showing that color scheme option with their respective chosen colors.Any suggestions over there.